# NODE и мои кривые руки

Tags: node.js

Здравствуйте. Возникли проблемы с переносом кода http://salejs.com/
Я пытаюсь перенести его с чужого сервера на свой, всё установил, внешне всё работает, но выдаёт такую ошибку при отправке формы с сайта (я предполагаю что при её обработке, так как сообщение об успешной отправке выходит, но письмо не приходит):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (cart.js:64)
xhr.onreadystatechange @ cart.js:64
```

Файл cart.js
Указанные строки

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(responded) return
  if(xhr.readyState == 4){
    responded = true
    if(xhr.status == 200) callback(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
    else callback(new Error(xhr.responseText))
  }
}
```

Консоли не нравится вот эта строка

```
if(xhr.status == 200) callback(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText))
```

Пробовал искать самостоятельно решение проблемы, но не получилось. Если не составит труда, подскажите решение или хотя бы укажите направление в котором искать. Спасибо.

Comment: Что приходит в ответе от сервера?

Comment: файл cart.js Закаловок ответа
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 17:33:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.6.30
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Etag: "753e-5495da3674266"

Comment: А тело? Вангую, там невалидный JSON - отсюда и ошибка.

Comment: В теле ответа (firebug и chrome debuger) показывает код cart.js: http://test.studionova.tech/client/cart.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас приведено сообщение об ошибке: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0" при выполнении JSON.parse. Это сообщение означает, что у аргумента JSON.parse самым первым символом оказалась буква v, чего быть не должно. Попробуйте в консоли браузера выполнить

```
JSON.parse('v');
```

и вы увидите такое же сообщение об ошибке.

Значение формата JSON - это либо объект (тогда первым символом должна быть { - левая фигурная скобка), либо массив (тогда первым символом должна быть [ - левая квадратная скобка).

Comment: Обычно `null` - тоже валидный JSON ;)

Comment: Спасибо! app.post не правильно прописал. Спасибо еще раз.